# R function to calculate number of variables to divide total by

Tags: r, function, average, mean

I have a data set with survey scores. I am summing the scores by row as follows:

```
d$total.score <- rowSums(d[, c("a", "b", "c", "d")], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I need to create another variable, the average score. If some of the variables had NA as a cell (e.g., 3+1+4+NA=8), the total I need to divide by will not be 4 but might be 2 or 3. What function can I use to calculate this number I need to divide by?

Thank you!

Comment: `mean(rowSums(d[, c("a", "b", "c", "d")], na.rm=TRUE),na.rm=T)` should do the trick.

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger They don't want the overall mean of the matrix, but rowwise, I think, like `rowMeans`.

Comment: `rowMeans(d[, c("a", "b", "c", "d")], na.rm = TRUE)` will give you the row means.

@Frank ... and I just saw your post :) Perfect!

Comment: rowMeans(d[, c("a", "b", "c", "d")], na.rm = TRUE)
worked perfectly, thank you,  @HoneyDippedBadger!